# Trying to do an integration testing with RSpec and Capybara. When running "rspec spec" it just opens the browser and does nothing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I am trying to run my integration tests using RSpec and Capybara using the command "rspec spec" , it used to run fine until recently it just opens the browser and stays there until timeout.

Here is the test code :

```
it "should see payment error if payment amount is smaller than product price", :js => true do 

    visit("/")
    find_link("A new product").click

end
```

Comment: what changed between it working and now not working?

Answer (score 1):

Do you change the version of your browser? If the browser version is not supported by webdriver, it might run into the case as you mentioned.

Comment: Yes, I did. I upgraded to Firefox 8 and since then it stopped working on my Ubuntu machine. However, even though I tried to downgrade Firefox the downgrade did not work and so the test would not work either...